# +1 button is unavailable or has stopped working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-plus, social-media

I have 3 google +1 buttons in the same wordpress page. But one of them fails when is clicked (in then float lateral widget) showing an `exclamation mark`.

[image]

When click again the following page is opened:
[+1 button is unavailable or has stopped working.](https://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=plusone_button_error&answer=1199142)  I am pretty sure that none of the described possible reasons occur.

The code for both is practically the same:

```
// float code (malfunction)
<div id="float_plusone">
<g:plusone size="tall" href="<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>" count="true"></g:plusone>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var po = document.createElement("script"); po.type = "text/javascript"; po.async = true;
po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
</script>

// above/below posts code (works)
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
</script>
<g:plusone size="medium" callback="googleplus_click"></g:plusone>
```

Any suggestion about is very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the URL the button is sending to the server to +1.

```
"id":"http://bestpushchairs.net/qc21/disclosure-policy/http%3A%2F%2Fbestpushchairs.net%2Fqc21%2Fdisclosure-policy%2F"
```

It looks like the button is taking the `href` value and assuming it is relative to the current path. Try not using `urlencode`.

Comment: +1 I removed `href="<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>"` totally. Working now. Thanks!